# rmarkdown: document knitting no longer working, pandoc error 83

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am working on an rmarkdown project on my work laptop. From one day to another I could no longer knit my markdown project (running line by line works fine).

I skimmed through many forums so far looking for answers in galaxies both close and far far away. Unfortunately no solutions worked (i.e. resetting .libPaths() from the 'server harddrive' to my local harddrive or deleting a certain file from the rmarkdown package folder.. can't remember what it was called though.. Ever since deleting the file though, instead of error no. 1 I get the error no. 83 as to be seen below)

So, I reinstalled RStudio but still.. it does not work.

The error I get is:

```
"C:/Users/name/rstudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS name.utf8.md --to docx --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash+smart --output name.docx --highlight-style tango --lua-filter "\\somedirectory/home/name/Data/My Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua" 
Error running filter \\?\somedirectory/home/name/Data/My Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua:
\\?\somedirectory/home/name/Data/My Documents/R/R-3.6.3/library/rmarkdown/rmd/lua/pagebreak.lua: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 83
Execution halted
```

Based on what I learned in the other posts, it could have something to do with the fact that rstudio is installed under C:/Users/... while the wd sometimes sets itself to what I called somedirectory/.. here.. 
But also manually setting the wd with setwd() to C:/Users/...did not work...

Help would be dearly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I have tried around a bit more...
the latest insights: 
if I try to knit it into a .pdf or .doc file, I get to error 83, whereas if I try to knit into an .html file, I get error 1...

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall rmarkdown?

Comment: Yes, I have tried re-installing rmarkdown.
It somewhat works, when I work from home through my home wifi…